# Apps Script raises permissions Exception when deployed as add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

1- We have developped an Apps Script for a Googgle Sheet (it exports each sheet in CSV UTF-8 format in the same folder)
It works for the sheet that contains the Apps script.

2 - When we deploy this script as add-on, we are able to install it.
We are prompted to connect to out google account and accept the following :
This will allow ExportCSVUTF8 to:
See, edit, create and delete all of your Google Drive files
See, edit, create and delete only the specific Google Drive files that you use with this app
See, edit, create and delete all your Google Sheets spreadsheets

3 - After deploying the add-on,  it is visible in the Add-ons menu but the Export function is not available.
In Chrome Debug Console, we can see this error message:
Google Apps Script: Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFolderById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)

In GCP-> Error reporting, we can see this error message
Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFolderById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) at unknown function

Did we miss something in the configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the mentioned authorizations to the manifest [as per this document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes)